# Is there an append operator for ByteString?

Tags: haskell, concatenation, bytestring

For String there is `++`, which has type

```
> :t (++)
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Evidently it doesn't work on `ByteString` because it isn't a list. I see the [`append`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:append) function but is there an operator for it?

Comment: You can use backticks, and thus work with ```bs1 `append` bs2```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ByteString has a Semigroup instance, so it can be combined in the usual way that semigroups are combined, with `(<>)`.

The same operator works for strings as well, because `String ~ [Char]`, and `[a]` has a Semigroup instance where `(<>) = (++)`.

```
Prelude Data.ByteString.Char8> unpack $ pack "abc" <> pack "def"
"abcdef"
```

Here I convert two Strings to ByteStrings, combine them as ByteStrings, and then convert back to String to demonstrate that it's worked.

Answer (score 4):

concat :: [ByteString] -> ByteString

O(n) Concatenate a list of ByteStrings.

Comment: Your answer may be a useful addition to the existing answers, but it would certainly benefit from a narrative explanation as well.